# ADF Pipeline -> How to not generate a file to blob when query result is empty in a copy data action

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline that queries a database then copies data to a blob storage container. This part works fine. However, I want it to simply not generate a file when the query result is empty. As in this case a file is generated no matter the result of the query and ADF considers this action a success, causing an unnecessary downstream email notification as the email portion will detect that the file exists and then send a notification about it.

Is there some method to do this? I have been reading Azure ADF settings for quite a while now and there doesn't seem to be an obvious route to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to query mode in source of copy activity and check the count of query. If it is zero, throw error else provide output. As per my understanding there is no out of the box feature to validate it within copy activity.

Or you can use a look up activity or script activity prior to copy to do the same validation